# Programmatically import code templates in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, code-templates

Is it possible to programmatically import code templates in eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can write your own plugin to provide code templates. At the moment i have no idea which extension point you have to use, but as a start you can look at the preferences page for the code templates how they do it in the code (press Alt + Shift + F1 in the preferences page to see the class of the page).